# Roundcube SMTP error: Failed to set sender

Tags: email, centos, smtp, roundcube

I've installed Postfix, dovecot, and Roundcube on Centos, I'm receiving emails but cannot send an email.

```
Trying to send email... 
SMTP send:  NOT OK(Failed to set sender 'm.alikhani@rayancommerce.com': (Code: -1))
```

this is smtp.log

```
[21-Oct-2023 16:41:22 +0330]: <oefpt1vg> Connecting to tls://127.0.0.1:587...
[21-Oct-2023 16:42:08 +0330]: <oefpt1vg> Recv: 220 mail.rayancommerce.com ESMTP Postfix
[21-Oct-2023 16:42:08 +0330]: <oefpt1vg> Send: EHLO mail.rayancommerce.com
[21-Oct-2023 16:42:08 +0330]: <oefpt1vg> Recv: 250-mail.rayancommerce.com
[21-Oct-2023 16:42:08 +0330]: <oefpt1vg> Recv: 250-PIPELINING
[21-Oct-2023 16:42:08 +0330]: <oefpt1vg> Recv: 250-SIZE 10240000
[21-Oct-2023 16:42:08 +0330]: <oefpt1vg> Recv: 250-VRFY
[21-Oct-2023 16:42:08 +0330]: <oefpt1vg> Recv: 250-ETRN
[21-Oct-2023 16:42:08 +0330]: <oefpt1vg> Recv: 250-STARTTLS
[21-Oct-2023 16:42:08 +0330]: <oefpt1vg> Recv: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
[21-Oct-2023 16:42:08 +0330]: <oefpt1vg> Recv: 250-8BITMIME
[21-Oct-2023 16:42:08 +0330]: <oefpt1vg> Recv: 250 DSN
[21-Oct-2023 16:42:08 +0330]: <oefpt1vg> Send: STARTTLS
[21-Oct-2023 16:42:08 +0330]: <oefpt1vg> Recv: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
[21-Oct-2023 16:42:08 +0330]: <oefpt1vg> Send: EHLO mail.rayancommerce.com
[21-Oct-2023 16:42:09 +0330]: <oefpt1vg> Send: HELO mail.rayancommerce.com
[21-Oct-2023 16:42:09 +0330]: <oefpt1vg> Send: MAIL FROM:<m.alikhani@rayancommerce.com>
[21-Oct-2023 16:42:09 +0330]: <oefpt1vg> Send: RSET
```

this is roundcube configuration:

```
$config['smtp_host'] = 'tls://127.0.0.1:587';
$config['smtp_debug'] = true;
$config['smtp_log'] = true;
$config['smtp_user'] = '';
$config['smtp_pass'] = '';

 $config['smtp_conn_options'] = [
  'ssl' => [
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true,
    'verify_depth' => 3,
    'cafile' => '/etc/httpd/ssl/server.crt',
  ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your settings file set `$config['smtp_user'] = '%u';` and `$config['smtp_pass'] = '$p';` and you should be ok.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).